# Refining MySQL select query using UNION and DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, database, select, distinct, union

I have a query in my php script that's not returning the desired data. The query is

```
select distinct require_category from users_require
```

which returns:

```
Diet
Experience
MeasurementsGain
MeasurementsLoss
MeasurementsMaintain
WeightGain
WeightLoss
WeightMaintain
Workout
```

But I only want

```
Diet
Experience
MeasurementsGain
WeightGain
Workout
```

I have refined my mysql query and returning corect results but I don't think its efficient enough:

```
select distinct require_category from users_require where require_category NOT LIKE '%Weight%' and require_category NOT LIKE '%Measurements%' union select distinct require_category from users_require where require_category = 'WeightGain' or require_category = 'MeasurementsGain'
```

Comment: The question is: By what rule do you want to include or exclude categories from your result? It looks like you may want to exclude the categories containing the words `'Loss'` and `'Maintain'`. Another possible rule would be `require_category in ('Diet', 'Experience', 'MeasurementsGain', 'WeightGain', 'Workout')`. But only you can define the rule you *actually* want applied.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner in my script I will be passing two variables that define what to be included  i.e $weight = 'WeightGain' and $measurements = 'MeasurementsGain'

Comment: So why does you result contain `'Diet'` then? It doesn't match either ot the two strings. Please think more carefully about the rule. The easiest way may be to look at every single category and say why it is or is not in the result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try following,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
require_category FROM users_require WHERE require_category NOT LIKE '%Loss%'
AND require_category NOT LIKE '%Maintain%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use some union

```
  select min(require_category)
  from users_require
  where require_category like 'Measurements%';
  union 
  select min(require_category)
  from users_require
  where require_category like 'Weigh%';
  union 
  select require_category
  from users_require
  where require_category not like 'Measurements%' 
  and require_category not like 'Weigh%';
```